# create fake data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have read through articles of how to create fakedata but i dont understand how to create fake data from already existing data.

can someone please guide me how I can do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to make a dictionary containing the 'correct'/'possible' values that `UG`/`PG` can have, like:

```
rolesdictug = {
    'account manager': [list of ug valeus],
}
rolesdictpg = {
    'account manager': [list of pg values]
}
```

and add other keys for other roles in the same manner.
Then, use:

```
import numpy as np
fakedf = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns)
fakedf['Current Role'] = np.random.choice( [list of all roles], size= required_size )
fakedf['UG'] = fakedf['Current Role'].apply( lambda x: np.random.choice(rolesdictug[x]) )
fakedf['PG'] = fakedf['Current Role'].apply( lambda x: np.random.choice(rolesdictpg[x]) )
```

This should work!

**Note:** The keys of the two dictionaries must be the same as all roles

Comment: This is pretty easy dude, c'mon
StackOverflow is not for making other people do your problems. This is only to help you.
All you have to do is get the lists of values, that you can directly get from the original dataframe in one line. 
If you don't know how to do that, I think you should leave this problem and read/watch a few pandas tutorials and about python programming in general.

Comment: Use [`df.groupby['Current Role']` like this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)